launching new containers from a container
I have a docker file of my api on rust
FROM lukemathwalker/cargo-chef:latest-rust-1.70.0 as chef
WORKDIR app

FROM chef AS planner
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM chef AS builder
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker.io
VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock

FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian11
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/blue_traktor_api /

ENV DOCKER_HOST unix:///var/run/docker.sock

CMD ["./blue_traktor_api"]

despite the fact that I say that the container will use the Docker socket from the host, mounting it in /var/run/docker.sock, I do not get access to it from the container and cannot launch containers from inside the current container. How do I solve the problem?
this command
 let docker_ps_output = Command::new("docker")
        .arg("ps")
        .arg("-a")
        .output()

should be executed in the api, but Failed to execute docker ps: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" } .. The error indicates that my application is trying to run docker ps, but Docker is not available in the runtime environment.

Look like /var/run/docker.sock of host is not binded. You should bind it like below example.
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <your_container_image>

how to add it to file?

You already have /var/run/docker.sock in your dockerfile.
You just need to attache your host machine /var/run/docker.sock to image volume.
If you provide me your post build command to run the container, I can update it for you.

Failed to execute docker ps: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" } .. The error indicates that my application is trying to run docker ps, but Docker is not available in the runtime environment.

Okay. In this case, you need to install docker inside the container. This will allow to run docker command inside the container. But don't use that, you should be connected with Host docker.sock.

The problem is: let docker_ps_output = Command::new("docker")
.arg("ps")
.arg("-a")
.output()

The problem was that I was installing Docker only in the build environment, not in the runtime environment. Since I am using a base image without a distribution for the final runtime, it did not include the Docker binary or any other binaries needed to execute Docker commands. I used a different base image:
FROM lukemathwalker/cargo-chef:latest-rust-1.75.0-alpine3.18 as chef
WORKDIR /app

FROM chef AS planner
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM chef AS builder
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM alpine:3.18
RUN apk update && apk add docker-cli
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/blue_traktor_api /
VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock
ENV DOCKER_HOST unix:///var/run/docker.sock
CMD ["./blue_traktor_api"]

